# "Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS" error when saving CSV to GeoPackage with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, export, csv, geopackage

I am using QGIS 3.32.3 and am trying to save a CSV file to a GeoPackage with PyQGIS using the current directory as part of the string. When trying to do this it shows:

> 'Incorrect parameter value for LAYERS'

in this specific case, when it works for everything else I've done it in, even the `OUTPUT` in the same process works, it's just the LAYERS that don't work here.

I am using QGIS 3.32.3

```py
dir = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")

processing.run("native:package", {'LAYERS':['file:///%s/data.csv?type=csv&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=longitude_site&yField=latitude_site&crs=EPSG:4326&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no'],'OUTPUT':'%s/Run_Data/data.gpkg'%dir,'OVERWRITE':True,'SAVE_STYLES':True,'SAVE_METADATA':True,'SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY':False,'EXPORT_RELATED_LAYERS':False})
```

As a working example:

```py
processing.run("native:fieldcalculator", {'INPUT':'%s/Run_Data/Neighbour_Sector.gpkg|layername=Neighbour_Sector'%dir,'FIELD_NAME':'area_sector','FIELD_TYPE':0,'FIELD_LENGTH':0,'FIELD_PRECISION':0,'FORMULA':'$area','OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'%s/Run_Data/Area_Neighbour.gpkg\' table="Area_Neighbour" (geom)'%dir})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html) of your CSV URI which will be accepted by the package algorithm.

A couple of things to note:

- The `%dir` suffix is missing from your CSV URI in the `LAYERS` property of the algorithm (might just be a typo).
- I renamed `dir` variable to `dir_` as `dir` is a reserved name in Python.

```py
dir_ = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./")

uri = r"file:///%s/data.csv?type=csv&trimFields=Yes&skipEmptyFields=Yes&maxFields=10000&detectTypes=yes&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude&crs=EPSG:3857&spatialIndex=yes&subsetIndex=yes&watchFile=yes"%dir_

# create a QgsVectorLayer from the URI
csv_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'csv', 'delimitedtext')

processing.run("native:package", {'LAYERS':[csv_layer], 'OUTPUT':'%s/Run_Data/data.gpkg'%dir_, 'OVERWRITE':True,'SAVE_STYLES':True,'SAVE_METADATA':True,'SELECTED_FEATURES_ONLY':False,'EXPORT_RELATED_LAYERS':False})
```